# How can I new an Object or call function in const declaration in Typescript 2.0.10?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm working on Angular 2 project (using angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.24 to scaffold the backbone). The default Typescript version after scaffolding is 2.0.3 but I updated it to 2.0.10, but I believe they have the same behavior I'm facing.
So my problem is I'm trying to new an Object (or call a function) in an const declaration, I expected the code will be something like this:

```
export const initialState: UIState = {
    a : null,
    b: new B()
}
```

But it throws an error:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'B', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function...
```

So my question is, is there any way I can do that with the current version of Typescript? If there isn't, how can I achieve the same goal with the code as readable as possible?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: That isn't a typescript error, from a google search it seems like an Angular2 AoT compiler error.

Comment: @NitzanTomer yes, I think so (because my Webstorm IDE said there was nothing wrong with the syntax), but for some reasons I can't change the version of angular-cli as well as Typescript, so I'm looking for a workaround for this :(